# iPhone 3G + iOS4 debug problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I recently updated our test iPhone 3G with the latest version of iOS 4 to be able to test our apps on the new OS. I regret that I didn't read the forums because after the update the device's performance suffered a lot. However this is not a problem because the device still works. The problem is that when I try to debug our app the device freezes for minute and reboots or closes the app and returns to the home screen. When it manages to stop at breakpoint it takes few seconds to step over or out and often there's no debug information about the variables. I assume that this is due to some memory issues because the new OS requires more memory space. I must point out that our app worked fine with the iPhoneOS 3.1.3 and the Xcode 3.2.2 with the 3.2 SDK. It is a Universal app and that runs fine on the iPad too.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem as well when one of my applications was consuming a lot of memory.  The background application that handles the remote debugging consumes quite a bit of ram (~15M the last time I had this problem).  If your app is fine in standalone mode and crashing under debug then you might be close to the limit running in standalone (as I was).

I noticed that making sure that all other applications were quited or if I rebooted the iPhone that I was able to debug my executable (this was until I found the copied object problem that was causing the memory bloat).

If you have a jailbroken iPhone then you will have other services running consuming memory as well.

the iPad has double the ram 256M than the 3G at 128M.

I have also seen a problem when opening an application with a url encoded with data that runs > 500K that it will crash springboard before your debug session is started with a delayed launch.

Comment: Heh, I noticed that as well. My app tries to download 12M data from a URL and maybe that is the problem. Yesterday I borrowed an iPhone 3G 3.1.3 device from a friend and the same app runs fine and I'm able to debug it.

I got suggestions from the apple dev forums to make clean install of the 3.2.3 Xcode. I will try that before reverting the iPhone to 3.1.3.

Thank you!